# How to use laravel mix define global javascript function

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I already have a function in resources/assets/js/common/utils.js

```
'use strict'

function test(){
   console.log('test');
}
```

How can I define utils.js as a global file and to be use any where?
Thanks for read my question!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use it outside of your bundled JavaScript files you can attach it to the `window` object

```
window.test = function () {
  console.log('test');
}
```

Which you can then use in other files, such as your blade template files as

```
window.test();
```

Or if you want to use it within your bundled JavaScript files you can import it as a module

```
// test.js
export default function test() {
    console.log('test');
}

// other.js
import test from 'test.js';

test();
```

As long as you are compiling your files with Laravel Mix as described [here in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-scripts).