# Javascript variable is not defined even though it is

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I am running a Laravel project and defined an object `wmDefaults` at the top of the `app.js` file like this:

```
var wmDefaults = {
    elemClass:'waitMe',
    effect : 'bounce',
    text : '',
    bg : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    color : '#000',
    maxSize : '',
    waitTime : -1,
    textPos : 'vertical',
    fontSize : '',
    source : ''
};
```

The `app.js` file has been included in the list of javascript external resources (see screenshot below)

[image]

However, after trying to access the variable in `console.log`, I get the error:

```
VM2335:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: wmDefaults is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Been writing Javascript code for 15 years but I'm embarassed I can't figure this one out. Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the variable is defined within scope of the function, not globally. Hard to tell from the limited code exampole.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the variable was defined in the root of the included javascript file. It was not inside the function. I have found the solution and added it as an answer to my question.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but note that while your solution may work, polluting the `window` with global variables is not good practice. I'd suggest finding an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured this out. Solution here: [How to use laravel mix define global javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484930/how-to-use-laravel-mix-define-global-javascript-function?rq=4)

I needed to use it outside of my bundled JavaScript files I had to attach it to the window object

```
window.wmDefaults = {
    elemClass:'waitMe',
    effect : 'bounce',
    text : '',
    bg : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
    color : '#000',
    maxSize : '',
    waitTime : -1,
    textPos : 'vertical',
    fontSize : '',
    source : ''
};
```